# AngularJS - Removing nested object if attribute equals true

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, splice

I always get confused when trying to remove/delete nested objects in angularjs. I'm hoping someone can help me with a sample project I'm working on and determine what I'm doing incorrectly.

I have a UI in which there are several rows of nested data within a table. The user will click "Delete" in any row to initiate removing that given row. Then (and this is where I'm struggling) they would click "Remove Deleted Items" to remove all nested objects that have the "deleted" attribute set to true.

I've created an example so showcase what I'm trying to accomplish....

http://plnkr.co/edit/FrKIuEobEBNQ4Kl7TPaC?p=preview

Here's my AngularJS Code:

```
var myApp = angular.module("fruit", ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.router']);

myApp.controller("FruitCtrl", function($scope) {

$scope.foods = [{
'id': 1, 'fruits': [{
  'id': '1',
  'name': 'Apple',
  'color': 'Red',
  'shape': 'Weird',
  'size': 'medium', 
  'deleted': false
}, {
  'id': '2',
  'name': 'Orange',
  'color': 'Orange',
  'shape': 'Sphere',
  'size': 'medium', 
  'deleted': false
}, {
  'id': '3',
  'name': 'Lime',
  'color': 'Green',
  'shape': 'Sphere',
  'size': 'small', 
  'deleted': false
}, {
  'id': '4',
  'name': 'Lemon',
  'color': 'Yellow',
  'shape': 'Sphere',
  'size': 'medium', 
  'deleted': false
}, {
  'id': '5',
  'name': 'Banana',
  'color': 'Yellow',
  'shape': 'Oblong',
  'size': 'large', 
  'deleted': false
    }]
  }];

  $scope.removeDeletedFruit = function(itemId, index) {
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.foods.length; i++) {
  if ($scope.foods[i].id === itemId) {
    $scope.foods[i].deleted.splice(index, 1);
    break;
  }
}
}

});
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Total Fruits: {{foods[0].fruits.length}}</h2>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeDeletedFruit(fruit.id, $index)">Remove Deleted Items</button>
    <table class="table" ng-repeat="food in foods">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Fruit</th>
          <th>Shape</th>
          <th>Color</th>
          <th>Size</th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="fruit in food.fruits" ng-class="{'delete-item': fruit.deleted, '': !fruit.deleted}">
          <td>  
            <span>{{fruit.name}}</span>
          </td>
          <td>  
            <span>{{fruit.shape}}</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>{{fruit.color}}</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>{{fruit.size}}</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="fruit.deleted = !fruit.deleted" ng-disabled="fruit.deleted">
                <span>Delete</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-neutral" ng-click="fruit.deleted = !fruit.deleted" ng-if="fruit.deleted" ng-disabled="!fruit.deleted">
                <i class="fa fa-history fa-1-5x"></i>
                <span>Undo</span>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Can someone assist with guiding me in the right direction or what's the best way to make this work?

Comment: Are you talking about something like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/j4uUOluWn7lbjByfqeOQ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Alon. This was pretty much good as it removes deleted=true objects, but was also looking to remove any items that had deleted set to true. Appreciate it though!

Comment: NP, I was confused because your button has `ng-click="removeDeletedFruit(fruit.id, $index)"` but `$index` (And also `fruit.id`) is only relevant inside `ngRepeat` and you're not inside any loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your function to use the [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
$scope.removeDeletedFruit = function(itemId, index) {
   angular.forEach($scope.foods, function(fruit){
     fruit.fruits = fruit.fruits.filter(function(a){return a.deleted == false})
    });
    }
```

demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WGkLiDWwGCBsjjtsSUxg?p=preview)

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: With this `itemId, index` are useless in the `removeDeletedFruit` buttons.